# Find the polynomial P(x) using 2 given limits

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial, with $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{P(x)+\sqrt{x+3}}{x^2-1}=l \in \mathbb{R} \quad \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)-x^3}{6x+2015}={1 \over 3}$$
a) Find $P(1)$, b) Find the $P(x)$ polynomial and c) Find $l$

a) As P(x) is a polynomial, it is continuous so $$\lim_{x\to 1}P(x)=P(1)$$ and I easily find that $P(1)=-2$. Now for $P(x)$ I will probably have to say that let $P(x)=α_νx^ν+α_{ν-1}x^{ν-1}+...+α_0$ and have to use the second given limit. Now how do I continue? Do I have to say that in order for the limit to be a number and not $+/- \infty$ It has to be of a certain degree? Even if that's true, when $x\to\infty$, I have to use the fact that I should take the highest degree of the numerator and denominator so do I get $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{α_νx^ν}{6}={1 \over 3}$? This feels wrong, cause there's also the $-x^3$ but I don't know that do with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second limit to be finite, the numerator must be a polynomial of degree $1$. As the limit is $\frac13$, the linear coefficient must be $2$.

Then

$$P(x)=x^3+2x+c$$ and $P(1)=-2$ gives us $c$.